# Exchange 2013 ActiveSync Unauthrized

Tags: exchange-2013

I have just updated to Exchange 2013 CU6 and now facing ActiveSync issue.

### Error

> Attempting to send the OPTIONS command to the server.

### Additional Details

An HTTP 401 Unauthorized response was received from the server. This may be the result of invalid credentials or a configuration problem on the Exchange Server.
HTTP Response Headers:
request-id: 61ff54a4-6125-4457-a41e-ddf24070f48c
X-CalculatedBETarget: 
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="",Negotiate,NTLM
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: 
Date: Mon, 22 Dec 2014 10:21:27 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Elapsed Time: 6330 ms.

After running  Test-ActiveSyncConnectivity -ClientAccessServer "" -MailboxCredential(Get-Credential ) -TrustAnySSLCertificate I get the following information in summery

Scenario: Options
Scenario Description: Issue an HTTP OPTIONS command to retrieve the Exchange ActiveSync protocol version
Error: **[System.Net.WebException]: The remote server returned and error: (401) Unauthorized**

Done a lot of google and changed and tested many configuration, now I am totally lost and unable to resolve the issue so need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you run the get-healthreport command and paste back the results or anything you notice in it that is unusual...

Comment: also might be worth giving this a run and posting the results.. https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Comment: @CharlesH After running the Get-Health got the following Unhealthy status

Comment: ActiveSync,FrontendTransport,MailboxTransport,MSExchangeCertif... (disabled) (LastTransitionTime:1/1/0001 !!),OWA, Search

Comment: I have provided the testconnectivity.microsoft.com result in the "additional details" section. I have pasted it with line brakes but they are all gone :(